# Change color of button inside fragment using thread

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity it includes fragments and it connects to the server. When server sends a message I want to change button color of my current fragment. I have tried to use a `Runnable` class in my fragment but it did not work. How can I do this?

This is code for my fragment:

```
public class changeBtn implements Runnable
{
    public String[] array;
    public changeBtn(String[] _array)
    {
        this.array = _array;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        acikMasalar=array;
        for (int i = 0;i<masalar.size();i++)
        {
            button = (Button) fragmentView.findViewWithTag(masalar.get(i));
            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }
}

    public void startProg(String[] array)
    {
        new Thread(new changeBtn(array)).start();
    }
```

and this is tcp client code that works in activity:

```
public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,TCPClient> {

        @Override
        protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {

            //we create a TCPClient object and
            mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                @Override
                //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                public void messageReceived(String message) {
                    //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                    srvrMessage = message;
                    if(srvrMessage!=null&&message!=null) {
                        acikMasalar = srvrMessage.split("\\*");
                        FragmentMasaDesing fragment = (FragmentMasaDesing) getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .getFragments().get(1);
                        if(fragment!=null) {
//                            fragment.changeButtonColor();
                            fragment.startProg(acikMasalar);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            mTcpClient.run();

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you tried? show me>.

Comment: Okay. I found my mistake but still I need one thing. I must change the color of buttons in a fragment in a different thread. What should I use for it? I shared my code.

Comment: If you found your mistake, share it for those who might have the same problem!.. I don't know how exactly your app works, but if you receive the message that one button should change its color but the fragment doesn't exist anymore, this information is lost. so you might want to think about a `SharedPreferences` or `SQlDatabase` solution and Fragments which check their buttonstatus in `onResume`?

Comment: I have just done a mistake wirting the constructure for changeBtn class. It works no. I will ask a new question about my other problem if I can't find a solution. Thank you for your attention.